# Subtracting dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
SELECT t2.Owner, a.accNumber, a.Rest, dateadd(day,1,MIN(a.Date)), MIN(b.Date)
  FROM t1 a
  LEFT JOIN t1 b ON a.accNumber=b.accNumber 
  LEFT JOIN t1 ON a.accountId = t2.accountId
  WHERE a.Date<b.Date 
    AND a.Rest<>0 
    AND a.accNumber=b.accNumber
  GROUP BY a.accNumber, a.Rest, t2.Owner
  ORDER BY t2.Owner
```

I want to subtract dates in 5 and 4th column `(MIN(b.Date) - dateadd(day,1,MIN(a.Date)))` and put it as 6th column, but simple `DATEDIFF(day, dateadd(day,1,MIN(a.Date)), MIN(b.Date))` doesn't work because of LEFT JOINs.

[image]

This is how it should look like. with current code, I can see only first 5 columns, I want to see 6th column either

[image]

This is how it looks like when I add `DATEDIFF(day, 4, 5)` to Select statement

Comment: Where is the table t2 coming from?

Comment: So what would you want in the date difference column if there is no b.date value

Comment: t2 is different table from where I retrieve 'Owner'

Comment: There is no `t2` in your select list. So, this select will not work at all.

Comment: there is (2ns word). This code actually works perfectly, what I want is just subtract those date values and add it as 6th column

Comment: So what do you want to do with the date difference if there's `NULL` because of the `LEFT JOIN`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ISNULL` function of SQL Server in this case as you have `NULL` because of the `LEFT JOIN`.

From your question it is not clear what you want to do but it could be used this way:

```
ISNULL(MIN(a.Date), 0)
```

or

```
MIN(ISNULL(a.Date, 0))
```

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain I understand the problem, but I can give you a solution for the short term. This will let you go ahead with development, and you can figure out what's wrong later.

Assuming your posted query works correctly, as your comments say, you can just treat it as a table.

Your query is

```
SELECT t2.Owner, a.accNumber, a.Rest, dateadd(day,1,MIN(a.Date)), MIN(b.Date)
  FROM t1 a
  LEFT JOIN t1 b ON a.accNumber=b.accNumber 
  LEFT JOIN t1 ON a.accountId = t2.accountId
  WHERE a.Date<b.Date 
    AND a.Rest<>0 
    AND a.accNumber=b.accNumber
  GROUP BY a.accNumber, a.Rest, t2.Owner
  ORDER BY t2.Owner
```

Name the columns, and wrap it in another SELECT statement. Something along these lines should work.

```
SELECT Owner, accNumber, Rest, Good_name, Another_good_name, 
       Another_good_name - Good_name Yet_a_third_good_name
FROM
    (SELECT t2.Owner, a.accNumber, a.Rest, 
            dateadd(day,1,MIN(a.Date)) Good_name, MIN(b.Date) Another_good_name
     FROM t1 a
     LEFT JOIN t1 b ON a.accNumber=b.accNumber 
     LEFT JOIN t1 ON a.accountId = t2.accountId
     WHERE a.Date<b.Date 
       AND a.Rest<>0 
       AND a.accNumber=b.accNumber
     GROUP BY a.accNumber, a.Rest, t2.Owner
     ORDER BY t2.Owner) AS Good_table_name
```

An alternative is to create a view from your first query, and select from the view.

Since there aren't any NULLs in your examples, and you don't mention them, I'm assuming you know how to deal with NULLs.